# Is Badrinath actually in India?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, temple, varaha

**Varahaapuran (adhay 140:)**

[image]
[image]
[image]
Bhagwan Varaha says -

> I live in kokaamukh in the base of the mountain at the intersection of "kokaa river" and "kausiki river" and will be known as Badri

This intersection is currently locted at Nepal in a place "Varahaachetra."

**For Badrikashram:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Varahapuran adhay 141.1:** (In hindi) "Usi himalaya parvat par, ek atyant goohaya staan hey, jo devatao ke liye bhi durlabh he. Ise Badarikashrama kahete he" Translation: In the same mountain (upper part of mountain where badri is) lies Badrikashrama. If Badrikasharama lies in the same mountain as Badri then they must both be near each other meaning they are both in Nepal. .What else can be said?

So then, how is it possible that Badrinath is located in india and not in Nepal, when clearly the two rivers mentioned in the shastra/Purana are located in Nepal?

**Note: I do not wish to offend anyone regarding my question. Our current thirthas are as holy regardless of their authenticity and I respect their location. Being a Hindu, I would never disrespect any thirth just because they do not match with shastras. Many thirthas have changed locations and this is why I try to find their original location. Sorry if I have offended anybody.**

Comment: Yes. Some believe original Badrinath is in Tibet or Nepal (not sure) and current temple is a Buddhist temple converted to Vishnu temple by Adi Shankara.

Comment: This is what [Sri M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Madhukarnath)'s Guru Sri Maheshwaranath Babaji says about Badrinath Temple in book [Apprenticed to a Himalayan Master](https://www.amazon.in/Apprenticed-Himalayan-Master-Yogis-Autobiography-ebook/dp/B007F2I3F0) "I asked Babaji what he thought of the Lama’s belief that the Buddha of Tholingmutt was the original Badrinath. “The fact is,” said Babaji, “in ancient times, there were Buddhist monks and Buddhist temples all over India.""(1/2)

Comment: "It is quite possible that the deity at Badrinath was that of a cross-legged Buddha which the great Shankaracharya turned into a cross-legged Narayana. Nowhere else does Narayana sit in Padmasana. What does it matter really? Purity of life and devotion are more important than being Buddhist or Hindu. Did you observe what a spiritually advanced soul the Rinpoche is? So let’s not get into such controversies.” (2/2)

Comment: @TheDestroyer As long as I am sure, Adi shankaracharya along with aauliya baba around 1300 years ago walked with the dharma flag from varahachetra to establish badrinath in uttarakhand, India. Statue of mukthinath built from Saligram silha (saligram stone) which Shankaracharya took from muktinath and placed it in india's uttarakhand calling the place badrinath. This evidence is provided in Nepal government's Rastriya abhilekhalaya (museum). According to shastras, badrinath sounds like its in Nepal because of the descriptions provided and that badrivan is in vaharachetra, Nepal.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I have been to Badrinath. I don't remember the murti of Vishnu being cross-legged, I had the mental impression He was standing. But I could be wrong as only the head of the murti can be seen and the rest is covered in garlands...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Maybe. I haven't visted Bhadrinath. But these are the words of Sri Maheshwaranath Babaji, who was disciple of [Sri Mahatavar Babaji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahavatar_Babaji).

Comment: If Badrinath was actually Badrinath then why is Badrivan not present there in Uttarakhand, India?

Comment: It's true that there is a rock called Badri near Kokamukha in Nepal.  But that has nothing to do with Badarikashrama, the abode of Nara and Narayana, which is very clearly described in being in Uttarakhand, India.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan where is your reference in all of this?

Comment: @RameshBhattarai Chapter 141 verse 1 is not talking about the Kokamukha mountain at all, it's talking about the Himalayas.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Please prove that. It clearly says that "Usi himalaya par..." meaning in the same mountain.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Varahapuran adhay 141.1: (In hindi) "Usi himalaya parvat par, ek atyant goohaya staan hey, jo devatao ke liye bhi durlabh he. Ise Badarikashrama kahete he" Translation: In the same mountain (upper part of mountain where badri is) lies Badrikashrama. If Badrikasharama lies in the same mountain as Badri then they must both be near each other meaning they are both in Nepal. .What else can be said?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Also for Badrikashrama to be real, saraswati nadi must be present and in a comment that I posted in my question: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16119/how-can-jamuna-river-be-in-india-when-shastras-say-otherwise I have shown that Saraswati intersects with Aruna. Also in Mahabharata, vanparvani, thirth yatra parva, Adhay 83, shlok no.151, it says "Saraswati and Aruna intersect". This means that Badrikasram is near Aruna river

Comment: Motilal Banarsidass version of Varaha Purana 140:4 says, "4. In that heap of rocks there is Brahmakunda. О Earth, I remain there in that snow." Can you update Sanskrit Verses?

Comment: @TheDestroyer do you want pictures of where I got the verses from?

Comment: @RameshBhattarai Yes.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I have inserted the pictures. Note: The verses are from the whole adhaya 140 and not just 140.4

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Badrivan, Saraswati nadi and Nara and Narayana parvat must be present for Badrikashram to be real. Because Saraswati intersects with Arun river of Nepal; it must be close to Arun. This means that Badrikashram is in Nepal. Also you say that Badrikashram "which is very clearly described in being in Uttarakhand, India." Please tell me where in the shastras it says this and how you related it to Uttarakhand.