# How can Jamuna river be in India when shastras say otherwise?

Tags: scripture, puranas, rivers

This is what shastras/Purana's say about the Jamuna river-

**Shrimad Bhagwat Mahapuran**, Pancham Skandha , Chapter 16, shlok 16-21:
[image]

**"In Mandarachal, A mango fell from a mango tree into a river changing the river's colour to yellow. Because of this, the river was called "Arun". On the downside of the river there was a [Syzygium cumini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syzygium_cumini) tree where one syzygium cumini fell and changed the colour of the river to black, again changing the name of the river to Jambu river (Also known as Jamuna)"**

This is also written in Garga Samhita, Visvajita khanda, Chapter 43, Shlok 4-5:
[image]

**"Because a Syzygium cumini fell on Jambunada, it was known as Aruna."**

This proves that Jambunada and Aruna river are the same.

In "Padmapurana", Swargakhanda, Chapter 38, Shlok 65:

[image]
The above picture translates to
**"Kausiki (Koshi) river intersects with Aruna"**

This intersection is in Nepal close to "Varahachetra" (eastern Nepal) where Jamuna river intersects with Kausiki. If this is the case, then how is it possible that Jamuna is in india? **Which one is the real Jamuna?** the one that the shastras/Puranas say or the one that is in Northern India?

**Note: I do not wish to offend anyone regarding my question. Our current thirthas are as holy regardless of their authenticity and I respect their location. Being a Hindu, I would never disrespect any thirth just because they do not match with shastras. Many thirthas have changed locations and this is why I try to find their original location. Sorry if I have offended anybody.**

Comment: That Bhagavatam chapter makes absolutely no mention of the Yamuna river: https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/16  It's talking about the Jambu river, which is not at all the same as the Yamuna river.  I don't know of any scriptures that relate the Jambu river and the Yamuna river.

Comment: I agree with Keshav, also Nepal was a part of Akhanda bharata so even jambu river and the intersection is part of ancient India. Devi sita was born in Nepal Mithila kingdom.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan in Brahma purana adhay 89 shlok 38-45 it says that Arun river (Known as Tapi in the shlok) and Yamuna intersect at a place called Gautamitat. Barun river when mixed with  Aruna river, was called Yamuna. On this post, according to shastras Aruna is Jambunada yes?  So in Padmapuran, swargakhanda, adhay 27, shlok 41 it says that saraswati nadi  intersects with Arun river, and in varhapuran adhay 174 shlok 85 it says that saraswati nadi intersects with Yamuna so Jambunada (Aruna river) is Yamuna.

Comment: @Yogi I search for thirthas in its original location so I do not wish to talk about nationalities. As Hindus, we shouldnt talk about nationalities and focus on the truth. The truth should be told to coming generations. We must believe what the shastras tell us and that is what I am trying to do. And talking about Sita mata's birthplace (current janakpur, Nepal), according to shastras, even that does not match with what the shastras tell us.

Comment: @RameshBhattarai - I think Jaambunad is a type of Gold found there its in Gita press version.

Comment: @RameshBhattarai The Srimad Bhagavatam does not say that the Jambu river and the Arunoda river are the same.  The Jambu river flows South and arises from the Jambu fruit.  The Arunoda river flows East and arises from Mangoes.  They are completely different rivers.

Comment: @RameshBhattarai Also, you haven't demonstrated that Arunoda is the same as Aruna.  In any vase even if you succeed in showing that the Yamuna intersects the Aruna, that the Aruna intersects the Saraswati, and that the Yamuna intersects the Aruna, that wouldn't demonstrate that the Yamuna is the same as the Aruna.  All it would show is that the three rivers form a triangle.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan The Srimad Bhagavatam does not say that the Jambu river and the Arunoda river are the same but; in garga samhita , Visvajita khanda, Chapter 43, Shlok 4-5 it says that: "Because a Syzygium cumini fell on Jambunada, it was known as Aruna." I will get back on your other questions.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Aruna is just a short form of Arunoda. It says in Shrimad Bhagwat Mahapuran, Pancham Skandha , Chapter 16, shlok 16-21 that "Arunoda is Jambunada" and in Garga Samhita, Visvajita khanda, Chapter 43, Shlok 4-5 it says that "Jambunada is Aruna" meaning Aruna is Arunoda.

Comment: No, verses 16-21 simply do not say that Arunoda is the same as the Jambu river.  They say the opposite, namely that Arunoda and the Jambu river flow in completely different directions.