# Is Kailāsa mansarovar actually in Tibet, China?

Tags: scripture, puranas, bhagavata-purana, rivers, geography

**Shrimad Bhagwat Mahapuran**, Pancham Skandha , Chapter 16

> While describing the character of Mahārāja Priyavrata and his descendants, Śukadeva Gosvāmī also described Meru Mountain and the planetary system known as Bhū-maṇḍala. Bhū-maṇḍala is like a lotus flower, and its seven islands are compared to the whorl of the lotus. The place known as Jambūdvīpa is in the middle of that whorl. In Jambūdvīpa there is a mountain known as Sumeru, which is made of solid gold. The southern side of the land is known as Ilāvṛta-varṣa. To the south of Sumeru are the mountains **Kailāsa** and Karavīra.

In the same chapter it also says:

> When all those solid fruits fall from such a height, they break, and the sweet, fragrant juice within them flows out and becomes increasingly more fragrant as it mixes with other scents. That juice cascades from the mountain in waterfalls and **becomes a river called Aruṇodā, which flows pleasantly through the eastern side of Ilāvṛta**.

Kailāsa is to the south of Sumeru parvat, Aruṇodā is in the eastern side and In my question [How can Jamuna river be in India when shastras say otherwise?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16119/how-can-jamuna-river-be-in-india-when-shastras-say-otherwise), I have shown that Aruṇodā (also known as Arun river) is in Nepal. If this is the case, **Which one is the real Kailāsa?** The one in Tibet or the one that touches Aruṇ river in eastern Nepal?

Reference: https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/16

**Note: I do not wish to offend anyone regarding my question. Our current thirthas are as holy regardless of their authenticity and I respect their location. Being a Hindu, I would never disrespect any thirth just because they do not match with shastras. Many thirthas have changed locations and this is why I try to find their original location. Sorry if I have offended anybody.**

Comment: There is no reason to believe that the Arunoda river is the same as the Arun river in Nepal.  And if you somehow succeeded in demonstrating that Arunoda is the same as Arun, that would mean that Nepal and Kailash are on different sides of Ilavrita Varsha.  Ether way, it would not imply that Kailash is in Nepal

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Aruna is just a short form of Arunoda. It says in Shrimad Bhagwat Mahapuran, Pancham Skandha , Chapter 16, shlok 16-21 that "Arunoda is Jambunada" and in Garga Samhita, Visvajita khanda, Chapter 43, Shlok 4-5 it says that "Jambunada is Aruna" meaning Aruna is Arunoda.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan How would it not be in Nepal? you are making claims without any references.

Comment: No, verses 16-21 do not say that Arunoda is the same as the Hambu river, they say that the Arunoda river flows East and the Jambu river flows South.  So they're completely different rivers.  In any case, Kailash is South of Ilavrita Varsha and Arunoda is East of Ilavrita Varsha, so if Nepal was East of Ilavrita Varsha then Kailash would not be in Nepal.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Kailash is inside Ilavrita Varsha and not south from it. Kailash is to the south of Sumeru. How can Nepal be east of Ilavrita Varsha when Ilavrita Varsha is in Nepal?

Comment: here is video explaining Dr. Subramaniam Swamy speaking to Chinese heads to open up Kailash for pilgrims after consulting with Kanchi periyavar.