# Ganga flows from Meru parvat but, where is Meru?

Tags: puranas, history, research

Srimad bhagvat mahapuran (5.17.3)

> After purifying the seven planets near Dhruvaloka [the polestar], the Ganges water is carried through the spaceways of the demigods in billions of celestial airplanes. Then it inundates the moon [Candraloka] and finally reaches Lord Brahmā’s abode atop Mount Meru.

Srimad bhagvat mahapuran (5.17.5)

> On top of Mount Meru, the Ganges divides into four branches, each of which gushes in a different direction [east, west, north and south]. These branches, known by the names Sītā, Alakanandā, Cakṣu and Bhadrā, flow down to the ocean.

Here it says that Ganga flows from meru parvat however, the parvat does not exist where Ganga currently is. So what I want to know exactly is, where is mount meru?

**Note: I do not wish to offend anyone regarding my question. Our current thirthas are as holy regardless of their authenticity and I respect their location. Being a Hindu, I would never disrespect any thirth just because they do not match with shastras. Many thirthas have changed locations and this is why I try to find their original location. Sorry if I have offended anybody.**

Comment: Can you pls.clarify abt. what  exactly do you want to know. 1) Where is mount meru ? Or 2) why mount meru is not there at "Gangotri"?

Comment: It's looks like from your previous questions that you are more interested in finding the geographical location and information or want the proof of various locations from countries point of view.This type of questions are not suitable on this site. Geography or History SE sites will be more suitable.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar How is this not a geographical question? Also Why is it not suitable? I am also quoting the shastras and not talking with no proof.

Comment: Since from the past there were lot's of changes happned on earts suface.River change roots & they disappeared and new rivers emerg.Also the landmass described in scriptures got divided into various countries.Like China , India ,Nepal , Bhutan etc.There are border disputes among countries also.From that point if view it's difficult to ascertain the location of any place according to description given in scriptures , which were written long ago....

Comment: Before such changes took place.You are only quoting from puranas for the description of the perticular place but your questions looks like  enquiry abt.geographical or geological data

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Vedas are written around 10,000 years ago. I doubt that in 10,000 years landmasses have changed so vastly that a thirth was shifted thousand of kilometers.

Comment: @RameshBhattarai The Vedas were never written, they're eternal.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan vedas existed eternally but were written 10,000 years ago.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan In mahabharat, vanparvani, thirth yatra parva, adhay 82, shlok 111, it says: "Saraswati nadi flows from Meru". In my comment on http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16119/how-can-jamuna-river-be-in-india-when-shastras-say-otherwise I have shown that saraswati intersects with aruna.  Therefore meru is near Aruna and since ganga flows from meru; ganga is also near aruna.

Comment: @RameshBhattarai I don't know why you mean by "written 10,000" years ago?  Do you mean committed to writing?  They were committed to writing fairly recently, before which they were transmitted through oral tradition.  Do you mean they were compiled 10,000 years ago?  If that's what you mean then that's wrong; they were compiled by Krishna Dvaipayana Vedavyasa 5000 years ago.  But the events spoken about in the Vedas do not correspond to either the time they were compiled, and definitely not to the time they were committed to writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

where is mount meru?

The answer itself is given in Shreemad Bhagvatam Skanda 5 Chapter 16 Shlokas 5 to 7. ( A Description of Jambūdvīpa).    Its told in bhagvatam that Among Bhumandala there are  seven dweepas.The innermost Kosha is "**Jambudweepa**" .At the **center of "Ilavruta" varsha** this "Meru Mountain is situated"

---

> यो वायं द्वीप: कुवलयकमलकोशाभ्यन्तर-कोशो  
>   नियुतयोजनविशाल:
>   समवर्तुलो यथा पुष्करपत्रम् 5॥॥
>
> yo vāyaṁ dvīpaḥ kuvalaya-kamala-kośābhyantara-kośo
>   niyuta-yojana-viśālaḥ samavartulo yathā puṣkara-patram.
>
> **Meaning** - The planetary system known as Bhū-maṇḍala resembles a lotus flower, and its seven islands resemble the whorl of that flower.
>   The length and breadth of the island known as Jambūdvīpa, which is
>   situated in the middle of the whorl, are one million yojanas [eight
>   million miles]. Jambūdvīpa is round like the leaf of a lotus flower.
>   [**SB 5.16.5**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/16/5)
>
> ---
>
> यास्मिन्नव वर्षाणि
>   नवयोजनसहस्त्रायामान्यष्टभि  
>      र्मर्यादागिरिभि: सुविभक्तानि
>   भवन्ति ॥6॥
>
> yasmin nava varṣāṇi nava-yojana-sahasrāyāmāny aṣṭabhir
>   maryādā-giribhiḥ suvibhaktāni bhavanti.
>
> **Meaning** -In Jambūdvīpa there are nine divisions of land, each with a length of 9,000 yojanas [72,000 miles]. There are eight mountains
>   that mark the boundaries of these divisions and separate them nicely.
>    [**SB 5.16.6**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/16/6)
>
> ---
>
> ऐषां मध्ये इलावृतं नामाभ्यन्तरवर्षं
>   यस्य 
>   नाभ्यामवस्थित: सर्वतः सौवर्ण: कुलगिरिराजो 
>  
>   **मेरुर्द्विपायामसमुन्नाह**: कर्णिकाभूतः कुवलय  
>   कमलस्य मूर्धनि द्वात्रिंशत सहस्त्रयोजनविततो मूले  
>   षोडशसहस्त्रं
>   तावतान्तर्भुम्यां प्राविष्ठ:॥7॥
>
> eṣāṁ madhye ilāvṛtaṁ nāmābhyantara-varṣaṁ yasya nābhyām avasthitaḥ
>   sarvataḥ sauvarṇaḥ kula-giri-rājo **merur** dvīpāyāma-samunnāhaḥ
>   karṇikā-bhūtaḥ kuvalaya-kamalasya mūrdhani dvā-triṁśat
>   sahasra-yojana-vitato mūle ṣoḍaśa-sahasraṁ tāvat āntar-bhūmyāṁ
>   praviṣṭaḥ.
>
> **Meaning**- Amidst these divisions, or varṣas, is the varṣa named Ilāvṛta, which is situated in the middle of the whorl of the lotus.
>   **Within Ilāvṛta-varṣa is Sumeru Mountain, which is made of gold.** Sumeru Mountain is like the pericarp of the lotuslike Bhū-maṇḍala
>   planetary system. The mountain’s height is the same as the width of
>   Jambūdvīpa — or, in other words, 100,000 yojanas [800,000 miles]. Of
>   that, 16,000 yojanas [128,000 miles] are within the earth, and
>   therefore the mountain’s height above the earth is 84,000 yojanas
>   [672,000 miles]. The mountain’s width is 32,000 yojanas [256,000
>   miles] at its summit and 16,000 yojanas at its base.
>
> [**SB 5.16.7**](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/16/7)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my questions  http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16175/is-kail%C4%81sa-mansarovar-actually-in-tibet-china and http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16119/how-can-jamuna-river-be-in-india-when-shastras-say-otherwise I have shown that Ilāvṛta-varṣa is to the west of Arun river. Like it says, Within Ilāvṛta-varṣa is Sumeru Mountain. If this is the case then how is it possible that ganga resides in gangotri and not near Arun river where Ilāvṛta-varṣa is which contains Sumeru Mountain. This is because Ganga flows from Sumeru parvat.

Comment: @RameshBhattarai It's true that there is a river called Arunoda that flows East from Ilavrita Varsha.  But we have no reason to believe that the Arunoda river has anything to do with the Arun river in Nepal.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Aruna is just a short form of Arunoda. It says in Shrimad Bhagwat Mahapuran, Pancham Skandha , Chapter 16, shlok 16-21 that "Arunoda is Jambunada" and in Garga Samhita, Visvajita khanda, Chapter 43, Shlok 4-5 it says that "Jambunada is Aruna" meaning Aruna is Arunoda.

Comment: No, verse 16-21 do not say that Arunoda is the Jambu river.

Answer (score 0):

In Yogic text Shiv Samhita, there is mention of Meru Parvat

CHAPTER II

(1) The Microcosm.

1. In this body, the mount `Meru` - i.e., the vertebral column - is surrounded by seven islands; there are rivers,
   seas, mountains, fields; and lords of the fields too.
2. There are in it seers and sages; all the stars and planets as well. There are sacred pilgrimages, shrines; and presiding deities of the shrines.
3. The sun and moon, agents of creation and destruction, also move in it. Ether, air, water and earth are also there.

(2) The Nerve Centers.

4. All the beings that exist in the three worlds are also to be found in the body; surrounding the `Meru` they are engaged in their respective functions.
5. (But ordinary men do not know it). He who knows all this is a Yogi; there is no doubt about it.
6. In this body, which is called Brahmanda (microcosm, literally the mundane egg), there is the nectar-rayed
   moon, in its proper place, on the top of the spinal cord, with eight Kalas (in the shape of a semi-circle).
7. This has its face downwards, and rains nectar day and night. The ambrosia further sub-divides itself into
   two subtle parts:
8. One of these, through the channel named Ida, goes over the body to nourish it, like the waters of the
   heavenly Ganges - certainly this ambrosia nourishes the whole body through the channel of Ida.
9. This milk-ray (moon) is on the left side. The other ray, brilliant as the purest milk and fountain of great joy,
   enters through the middle path (called sushumna) into the spinal cord, in order to create this moon.
10. At the bottom of the `Meru` there is the sun having twelve Kalas. In the right side path (Pingala) the lord of
    creatures carries (the fluid) through its rays upwards.
11. It certainly swallows the vital secretions, and ray-exuded nectar. Together with the atmosphere, the sun
    moves through the whole body.
12. The right-side vessel, which is pingala is another form of the sun, and is the giver of nirvana. The lord of
    creation and destruction (the sun) moves in this vessel through auspicious ecliptical signs.